# Can't download android app from eclipse to my device

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I'm trying to run an android app from eclipse on my device (moto droid2).  I've followed all the instructions I can find to set up both the device and my computer (Win7) so that I can run the app on my device.  I'm not getting the option to download to the device.

I found [Installing the USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#InstallingDriver), but there is no "Devices" section.  There is a "Device Manager", but no "Android Phone" in the right pane.  In the "Other devices" section there is a "Motorola ADB Interface".  I went through "Update Driver Software".  I selected "\extras\google\usb_driver" in the path, but it said it failed to update the driver.

On the phone, I turned on "Unknown Sources" in Application settings, and enabled USB Debugging.

I connected the phone to my computer with my usb cable.  If I look in Windows Explorer, I can see the files from the phone.

In the Run Configuration, I set the Target Selection Mode to Manual.  I ran the application, but it never gave me the option to install on the device.

I must be missing something.

Comment: restart the phone?, and restart adb

Comment: what happens if you run `adb devices` (located in `/platform-tools/` folder of your android install directory)?  Does your device show up in that list?

Comment: adb devices just lists my emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the usb driver for this device, 
I had issues with a HTC Desire HD connecting to ADB but after installing the HTC drivers in windows 7 worked fine.

http://www.motorola.com/Support/US-EN/Support-Homepage/Software_and_Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers
I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, if you read my original post again, you'll see that I said that I tried to install/update the drivers, but I'm apparently not succeeding.

Comment: It appears that this was the missing link.  Installing drivers from the moto site got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your device to "charge only" mode, so your sd card isn't mounted as a drive to your machine.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

If that still doesn't work, it could be:

- a faulty cable
- you may need to download manufacturer specific drivers for your device.

Comment: How do you set it to "charge only"?

Comment: It varies per device/manufacturer, but usually you can do it in the status/notification bar.  There will be an option to set the usb connection mode, ex: charge only, disk drive, sync, etc.

Comment: I found it.  I set it to charge only, then killed and restarted the adb server, but adb devices still doesn't list the device.

Answer (score 1):

Those drivers at d.android.com are only for Google devices (Nexus 1, Nexus S, etc.) You will need to install the drivers for your device from the device mfg's website. Can't paste links yet but did you install drivers from Moto's web site?

Answer (score 0):

Some Moto phone has specific control customization for USB connection management, set it to **Portal & Tools** seems to help ADB recognize your phone.

A similar discussion posted at Android Developer mailing list [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3571170253b99d0).

A step-by-step setup with screenshots can be found [here](http://kmansoft.com/2010/08/19/enabling-adb-on-the-motorola-milestone/)

Hope that helps.